# how use in Java method .or and .orElseThrow

Tags: java, jpa, findby

Is even possible add more method inside of
`findbyId(id).orElseThrow(() -> new BusinessException("bug"));`

and not just Exception ?
so something like

`.orElseThrow(() -> { //do something here new BusinessException("bug") });`

or use ".or" method where I can put more methods, I don't need Exceptions. So if doesn't exist then
//do this
// and this

because with classic method you add Entity as a Optional,then check in condition if isPresent and then if not, you can do couple more thing in else{}

Comment: So just use an `if (someOptional.isPresent())`?

Comment: Is the absence of an entity with a given ID a business exception or a programming error? Why does the user have the ID but the entity is not present? Do you want to soft-delete the entity instead?

Comment: Maybe you are looking for [Optional::map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#map-java.util.function.Function-)?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether I understand you correctly and assume you want to add additional logic to `orElseThrow` for the first part.

## Add additional logic to `orElseThrow`

`orElseThrow` always throws an exception and that exception is taken from the lambda.

If you want to add functionality before throwing the exception, make sure to return it:

```java
yourOptional
    .orElseThrow(() -> {
        //additional logic possible here
        //will be executed if optional is empty
        return new YourException();
    });
```

However, if you want to add logic that decides whether or not to throw an exception, you can use `or` to map to an optional containing the value to return that is empty if you want to throw the exception. Then, use `orElseThrow`:

```java
yourOptional
    .or(() -> {
        //additional logic possible here
        //will be executed if optional is empty
        if(shouldThrow()){
            return Optional.empty();
        }
        return Optional.of(someValue);//if you originally had an Optional<T>, someValue should be assignable to T
    })
    .orElseThrow(() -> {
        return new YourException();
    });
```

## no exception

In case you don't want to throw an exception but have some other logic, you can use `orElseGet`.
This method just executes a lambda expression if the `Optional` is empty and returns the result:

```java
yourOptional
    .orElseGet(() -> {
        //this will be executed if the Optional is empty
        return someValue;
    });
```

Comment: No I meant,something like .orElse( () -> System.out.println("error"));
so if drop that thing,do something else,without if etc.

Comment: So you don't need the result? Then you can just use `orElseGet`, `ifPresentOrElse` or similar.